# Page.existingPageName page instantiation says Variable doesn't exist

Tags: apex, pagereference

I've got a method that redirects to another page. It does work this way:

```
public PageReference redirectToSetup() {
  return Page.SetupPage;
}
```

and this way:

```
public PageReference redirectToSetup() {
  PageReference page = new PageReference('/apex/SetupPage');
  page.setRedirect(true);
  return page;
}
```

but not his way:

```
public PageReference redirectToSetup() {
  PageReference page = Page.SetupPage;
  page.setRedirect(true);
  return page;
}
```

I'me getting the following error when trying to save it:

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Page.SetupPage

What am I doing wrong? Documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_controller_navigation_methods.htm) is using the same pattern, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
public PageReference redirectToSetup() {
  PageReference pageRef = Page.SetupPage;
  pageRef.setRedirect(true);
  return pageRef;
}
```

Apex is case insensitive.

Comment: d'oh! totally forgot about it. thanks heaps! (it works:)